# How to use elements in autoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, text, autocomplete, integer

I want to convert choosen element to Integer. When it's done I want to add a random number between 1-20 to choosen Integer. Than show up that number in Toast.

Comment: Convert element to an integer? What element are you trying to convert?

Comment: Elements of AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: What problems are you facing?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Do you know what is AutoCompleteTextView? Why are you not using edittext?

Comment: I think AutoCompleteTextView would make easier using the program from users point of view.

Comment: use widget for AutoCompleteTextView.Try this : "CustomAutoCompleteTextView"

Answer (score 0):

To convert a value coming from a TextView to an integer, you just need to use the following code:

```
EditText tViewNum = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.number);
String strWord = tViewNum.getText().toString();

Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(21 - 1) + 20;

String Randomiser = strWord + " " + il; //the +" "+ is used to add a space between the word and the random number. 

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Randomiser + "//any other text you wish to include", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Note that the random number given here is between 1 (inclusive) and 20 (inclusive).

Comment: Yes, I think this will be the solution, but how will program know what was typed in to EditText. It's not the same for example if user type in pear or apple.

Comment: because you are using this line to get the data from the TextView:   `int num = Integer.parseInt(tViewNum.getText().toString());`

Comment: @mlaferla Toast takes String as second parameter, not int. Please edit it and there is class mismatch in first line, it has to be EditText. Please change the context to this or getApplicationContext(). And I don't know why are you using `rootView`. Do you mind explaining?

Comment: @Adrian For your purpose you should use `EditText` not `AutoCompleteTextView`. The above code is using `EditText`. If you want to use ACTV, you need to store the values in an Array first.

Comment: @mlaferla why are you using `rootView`?

Comment: The way I had implemented it was in a fragment not in an activity.

Comment: I only don't want to type number into EditText, but word, than it should recognize what word is typed in.

Comment: so each random number should be assigned to a different word?

Comment: No, that Word should be = some number, saved before in program. And than when this word is typed in and pushed the button, it should add that random number.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if this has helped you. Otherwise, we would be happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

use a widget forAutoCompleteTextView.

"CustomAutoCompleteTextView"

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

  public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

@Override
protected void performFiltering(final CharSequence text, final int keyCode) {
    // String filterText = "";
    super.performFiltering(text, keyCode);


}

/**
 * After a selection, capture the new value and append to the existing
 * text
 */
@Override
protected void replaceText(final CharSequence text) {
    super.replaceText(text);


 }
}
```

Your Xml will be like this:[Depend where you add your widget ]

```
    <com.example.widget.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/sent_message_to"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:imeOptions="actionSend"

        android:hint="name"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:completionThreshold="3"

        />
```

Main class

you can set adapter for list value or declare  array

```
private AutoCompleteAdapter mAutoCompleteAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> mArray = new ArrayList<String>();
private CustomAutoCompleteTextView mAutoFillTextView;
.....

mAutoFillTextView = mViewUtils.createAutoFillTextView(view.findViewById(R.id.sent_message_to), false);

        mAutoCompleteAdapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity(), mArray);
        mAutoFillTextView.setAdapter(mAutoCompleteAdapter);
```

and
      mAutoFillTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

```
            try {


                mArray.clear();
                String string = s.toString().trim();

                if (mAutoFillTextView.getThreshold() <= string.length() && mAllowRequest) {
                    //GET DATA  TO LIST

                } 


            } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```